# jQuery - AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on an app that sends a POST request to a web service. My POST request looks like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
  type: 'POST', url: getEntityUrl(), cache: 'false',
  contentType:'application/json',
  headers: {
    'api-key':'myKeyHere',
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
  },
  data: {
    firstName:'Jon',
    lastName:'Smith'  
  },
  success: function() { alert('good job'); },
  error: function() { alert('oops'); }
});
```

When I execute this, I'm getting a 400 Bad Request. I watched the request in Fiddler. I noticed that the parameters I sent are being sent as `"firstName=Jon&lastName=Smith"`. However, they need to be sent across as JSON like I have them defined in the `data` parameter. I confirmed this is the problem by modifying the request in the composer in Fiddler. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I also had this problem. I could not solve, and I used GET method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass jQuery a plain object through the `data` parameter (as you do here) then it will encode the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Just setting the `contentType` is insufficient.

If you want to send JSON then you must encode it yourself. You can use `JSON.stringify` for that.

```
data: JSON.stringify({
  firstName:'Jon',
  lastName:'Smith'  
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `stringify` the data like following.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
    url: getEntityUrl(), 
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
        'api-key': 'myKeyHere',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({ firstName: 'Jon', lastName: 'Smith' }), //change here
    success: function () { alert('good job'); },
    error: function () { alert('oops'); }
});
```